# Has it ever been officially stated that Evelyn is Bill's mother?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, caprica

A number of websites list Evelyn Adama as Bill Adama's mother. Granted we could assume that this is the case, given that

1. Evelyn was present at the ceremony with Bill shown in the "Caprica" epilogue
2. Joseph and Evelyn were dating as of the end of "Caprica".

However I can't find any official confirmation that Bill's mother was called "Evelyn" either in the main series or in "Blood and Chrome". Has this ever been confirmed anywhere in canon or official sources, or is it just an assumption?

Comment: *Has this ever been confirmed anywhere in canon or official sources* - Is there a reason why Caprica isn't included as canon and/or an official source?

Comment: @Steve-O I would count Caprica as an official source, but I don't think it was confirmed in Caprica either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was addressed in [an interview](http://web.archive.org/web/20131101184846/http://www.capricatimes.com/the-caprica-times-exclusive-interview-kevin-murphy) with Caprica showrunner Kevin Murphy.

> **The Caprica Times:** ***Were we to learn in Season 2 who the biological mother of William Adama really is?***
>
> ***Kevin Murphy:*** **It was Evelyn.** *The name of the Admiral’s birth mother was established in BSG. It was on a prop or set-dressing, I forget exactly what. Once we figured out what was going to happen to poor doomed Willy, I went back into the first 10 episodes (which hadn’t been finished yet) and retroactively changed the name of Teryl Rothery’s character from “Justine” to “Evelyn.” You can see the ADR moments in the cuts if you’re watching the first 10 carefully. You never see anyone’s lips say the name “Evelyn” on camera in a close angle.*